# Hive Pig anti join

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to merge two datasets: `Events` and `mortality` by `patientid`. Events have all the `patientid` including the patientid in `mortality`, but didn't have the `timestamp` and `label` (always equal 1) in `mortality`. I want to extract all records in `events` but not in `mortality`.

```
-- load events file
events = LOAD '../sample_test/sample_events.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (patientid:int, eventid:chararray, eventdesc:chararray, timestamp:chararray, value:float);

-- select required columns from events
events = FOREACH events GENERATE patientid, eventid, ToDate(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS etimestamp, value;

-- load mortality file
mortality = LOAD '../sample_test/sample_mortality.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (patientid:int, timestamp:chararray, label:int);

mortality = FOREACH mortality GENERATE patientid, ToDate(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS mtimestamp, label;

--To display the relation, use the dump command e.g. DUMP mortality;

-- ***************************************************************************
-- Compute the index dates for dead and alive patients
-- ***************************************************************************
eventswithmort = JOIN events BY patientid, mortality BY patientid;-- perform join of events and mortality by patientid;
eventswithmort = FOREACH eventswithmort GENERATE events.patientid, events.eventid, events.etimestamp, events.value, mortality.mtimestamp, mortality.label;

aliveevents = FILTER eventswithmort BY mortality::label != 1;
```

My question is for last row of code should I use `label != 1` or `label is null`? It seems that I always got an empty dataset.

Answer (score 1):

```
eventswithmort = FOREACH eventswithmort GENERATE events.patientid, events.eventid, events.etimestamp, events.value, mortality.mtimestamp, mortality.label;
```

not totally sure this is the syntax for generating the data, instead of . should you not use ::

if you want rows in events but NOT in mortality then the join should be left outer, pig default is an inner join.

> eventswithmort = JOIN events BY patientid LEFT OUTER, mortality BY
> patientid;

then for each eventswithmort you can FILTER by mortality::label IS NULL;